# maximum subarray variant

Tags: code-golf, math

**Problem**
There is a circular track containing fuel pits at irregular intervals. The total amount of fuel available from all the pits together is just sufficient to travel round the track and finish where you started. Given the the circuit perimeter, list of each fuel pit location and the amount of fuel they contain, find the optimal start point on the track such that you never run out of fuel and complete circuit.

**Sample Input**

```
(location, fuel)

(0/100, 6)
(2,16)
(18,1)
(30,45)
(84,5)
(92,27)
```

circuit length - 100, total fuel-100

Comment: Most of the simplifying assumptions are obvious, but what do you mean by "optimal"? And given that whatever you mean I can construct an input which doesn't have a unique answer, how should that be handled?

Comment: "optimal" means a choosing a start point X such that you can finish journey and again reach back X, without failing in the middle due to fuel outage. You can run out of fuel after crossing a few pits, if calculation isn't done properly. In case of multiple answers, list all.

Comment: If the "total amount of fuel available from all the pits together is just sufficient to travel round the track and finish where you started" then there is either one or zero solutions. The one solution would be to visit every fuel pit in sequential order. This problem is embarrassingly trivial.

Comment: Rescinded. I see what you're talking about. I agree with Peter Taylor though, I think by "optimal" you mean "only".

Comment: Start with an arbitrary amount of fuel at any point in the circuit and plot the cumulative amount of fuel as you travel around the circuit, allowing it to go negative if necessary. The minima of the graph are the possible starting positions.

Comment: You have some sample input data, and expected output data. Or is it enough if our program prints "solved!"? Would a typical problem look like: '0,0,2,0,0,4,0,0,7,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0' where every step costs 1 unit, and numbers higher 0 mean that you get n units there? With the last element of the array connected to the first - not easily displayable in the comments.

Comment: O(n^2) solution is straightforward. Visit each fuel pit and try to ascertain if can be valid start point. But this would need 2 nested for loops. I am looking for an optimized O(n) solution which would visit each node exactly once. (code length no bar)

Comment: So what is the challenge then? If two solutions are both O(n), how do you determine which one is better? Also, does it matter what the input is?

Comment: @JoelCornett The challenge is to get the most optimized solution, and verify it from profiling. Input can be anything which covers all test cases, but to be fair all solutions needs to be profiled against same input.

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript 140 chars**

For the first solution, I assume that the fuel pits are provided in order order of location around the track and in the form:

```
var fuelPitInfo = [
    {
       location: 2,//The location from some point on the track
       fuelDistance: 1//The distance you can travel with the fuel from this stop
    },
    ..
]
```

Thus, a potential non code-golfed JavaScript function to calculate a working starting location is as follows ([test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/kEFay/)):

```
function calculateStartingLocation(trackLength, fuelPitInfo) {
    for(i=0;;i++){
        var fuelPit = fuelPitInfo[i];
        var remainingFuelDistance = fuelPit.fuelDistance;
        for(j=i+1;;j++){
            var nextFuelPit = fuelPitInfo[j = j % fuelPitInfo.length];
            if (i == j) return fuelPitInfo[i].location;
            remainingFuelDistance -= (nextFuelPit.location - fuelPit.location + trackLength) % trackLength;
            if (remainingFuelDistance < 0) break;
            remainingFuelDistance += nextFuelPit.fuelDistance;
            fuelPit = nextFuelPit;
        }
    }
}
```

And the code-golfed function version (**140 chars**) is as follows (assuming `location` is replaced with `l` and `fuelDistance` is replaced with `d` in the provided `fuelPitInfo` object) ([test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/syd9p/)):

```
function a(b,c){for(i=0;e=c[i],f=e.d;i++){for(j=i+1;g=c[j=j%c.length];){if(i==j++)return c[i].l;f-=(g.l-e.l+b)%b;if(f<0)break;f+=g.d,e=g;}}}
```

Comment: +1 briguy, please add a small explanation to your code, and also worst case complexity.

Comment: @jerrymouse:  Sure.  You start at a fuel pit, only consider one direction around the track (if there is enough fuel to make it one way, there is enough to make it the other), and then check that you can make it to each fuel pit in order.  You try the next fuel pit if you fail, or return the location of a valid starting fuel pit if not.  This is O(n^2), and I wrote it to be concise rather than efficient, because it was before your comment that you wanted the "most optimized" solution, and because pre-mature performance optimization is almost always a bad idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

### D (98 chars)

the input is a int array with the amount of fuel with 0 if there is no fuel there

```
int f(int[] a){
    for(int s,r=-1,i=0;;i++){
        if(r+a.length==i)
            return r;
        if(--s<0){
            r=i;s=0;
        }
        s+=a[i%$];
    }
}
```

I start at index `0` with `0` fuel and whenever `s` falls below 0 I set that spot as my new start and reset `s` to `0`

if there is a solution you will find it in O(n) time or loop forever

Comment: +1 ratchet, please add a small explanation to your code, and also worst case complexity. Please format code to be more verbose..

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 183

```
import sys
f=[map(int,_.split()) for _ in open(sys.argv[1])]
l=len(f)
s=[]
for i in range(l):
\tu,d=zip(*(f[i:]+f[:i]))
\tif all(sum(u[:j])<sum(d[:j])for j in range(l+1)):s+=[i]
print s
```

This program takes input in the form of a file consisting of N lines, where N is the number of fuel depots. Each line contains integers A and B, where A is the amount of fuel at the depot, and B is the distance to the next fuel depot. Example:

```
7 5
6 7
4 3
```

Output is the string representation of a list containing the indices of the fuel depots that are valid starting points. In this case, it outputs:

```
[0, 2]
```

Meaning that starting at either fuel depot 0, or fuel depot 2 will allow the vehicle to make it all the way around the circle.

Comment: +1 joel, please add a small explanation about how your code works, and also worst case complexity.

Answer (score 1):

## APL, 48 chars

```
{i/⍨{∧/0≤-\,m⊖⍨⍵-1}¨i←⍳↑⍴m←⍵[;2],⍪2-⍨/⍵[;1],100}
```

I'm not sure what the conditions are for this golf, but I wrote a straightforward O(n²) solution.

**Explanation**

This function accepts a matrix with the positions and amounts of fuel, with the condition that the length is 100 and that the first pit is at position 0:

```
      p
 0  6
 2 16
18  1
30 45
84  5
92 27
```

The first operation is to take the first column, append 100 at the end, and take the differences of each pair of values, to get the distances between each pair of pits:

```
      d←2-⍨/p[;1],100
      d
2 16 12 54 8 8
```

Then it builds a new matrix with the amounts of fuel in the first column and the distances in the second:

```
      m←p[;2],⍪d
      m
 6  2
16 16
 1 12
45 54
 5  8
27  8
```

Then it enumerates the naturals from 1 up to the number of rows (pits) and selects those which pass a given test:

```
      i←⍳↑⍴m
      ({ . . . }¨i)/i
```

The test is to rotate the rows of the matrix by the index amount minus 1, so let's say if we want to start from the 3rd pit, it rotates 2 rows from the top to the bottom:

```
      r←(3-1)⊖m
 1 12
45 54
 5  8
27  8
 6  2
16 16
```

Then it flattens the elements of the matrix in row-major order and it scans their alternating sum. Scanning means to compute the alternating sum of just 1, 2, 3… up to all the elements of the vector:

```
      a←-\,r
      a
1 ¯11 34 ¯20 ¯15 ¯23 4 ¯4 2 0 16 0
```

We can see that by starting from the 3rd pit the tank is first filled up to 1, then drained down to -11, then filled up to 34, and so on. The next step is to ascertain whether all the numbers are ≥0, which in this case they are not:

```
      ∧/0≤a
0
```

If they did, the starting position would be included in the resulting set of good starting positions. And that's all.

---

As somebody mentioned, one could probably compute this alternating sum just once and use the minima as starting positions. I'll do it as a second version.